# error con la carpeta de /tmp

Tags: laravel-5

Veran, tuve un extraño error con algunos ficheros de Laravel que me impidian acceder a mi pagina.
Note que los ficheros que daban error estaban en la carpeta /tmp, por lo que borre la carpeta entera.
Tras eso, aparentemente la pagina funciono de nuevo, pero ahora me topo con este problema:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¡No consigo incluir fotos en el formulario!
Las imagenes que ya estuvieran se siguen viendo y aquellos formularios que no pidan imagen funcionan a la perfección. El problema es cuando intento subir una imagen en un formulario.
¿Como lo arreglo ahora?

Comment: Lo primero que me viene a la cabeza es ¿tienes espacio libre en la partición?

Comment: @SJuan76 ¿A que te refieres?

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo he solucionado.
Al crear un nuevo proyecto automaticamente se crea la carpeta tmp, así que creo un nuevo proyecto y copio en el las demas carpetas.